# Mule project in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, mule

I am working on a mule application. The application is successfully packaged and installed on a mule stand alone server.

The same project when tried to run on a eclipse ide is giving errors. Struggling with this error.

I am using Maven as the builder.

Please help. Given below is the error.

```
    INFO: Refreshing org.mule.config.spring.MuleApplicationContext@148238f4: startup date [Thu Nov 29 09:36:07 EST 2012]; root of context hierarchy
    Nov 29, 2012 9:36:07 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
    INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/.m2/repository/org/mule/modules/mule-module-spring-config/3.3.0/mule-module-spring-config-3.3.0.jar!/mule-spring-config.xml]
    Nov 29, 2012 9:36:07 AM org.springframework.util.xml.SimpleSaxErrorHandler warning
    WARNING: Ignored XML validation warning
    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
        at ........

    Nov 29, 2012 9:36:07 AM org.mule.MuleServer shutdown
    SEVERE: 
    ********************************************************************************
    Message               : Line 6 in XML document from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/.m2/repository/org/mule/modules/mule-module-spring-config/3.3.0/mule-module-spring-config-3.3.0.jar!/mule-spring-config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    Code                  : MULE_ERROR-71999
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Exception stack is:
    1. cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'. (org.xml.sax.SAXParseException)
      com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper:195 (null)
    2. Line 6 in XML document from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/.m2/repository/org/mule/modules/mule-module-spring-config/3.3.0/mule-module-spring-config-3.3.0.jar!/mule-spring-config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'. (org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException)
      org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader:396 (null)
    3. Line 6 in XML document from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/.m2/repository/org/mule/modules/mule-module-spring-config/3.3.0/mule-module-spring-config-3.3.0.jar!/mule-spring-config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'. (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
      org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry:117 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/lifecycle/InitialisationException.html)
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Root Exception stack trace:
    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
        + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
    ********************************************************************************

    Nov 29, 2012 9:36:07 AM org.mule.MuleServer shutdown
    SEVERE: 
    ********************************************************************************
    * A Fatal error has occurred while the server was running:                     *
    * cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.                   *
    * (org.xml.sax.SAXParseException)                                              *
    *                                                                              *
    * The error is fatal, the system will shutdown                                 *
    ********************************************************************************
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: When you say "Eclipse IDE" do you mean "Mule Studio" or just plain Eclipse? If plain Eclipse, how do you start Mule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution for my problem. 
The reason is the spring beans are declared in a applicationContext.xml file outside of the mule-config and then imported. 
This was causing the issue.
When all the spring beans are declared inside the mule-config its working fine now.

Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the Spring schema location in your Mule configuration from 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd 
to
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd

Comment: Tried that... but still the same issue.         xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd

Comment: Can you edit your question with the new exception you get after you made the change suggested by Seba